# AEM Stop command not working for Publish instance

Tags: aem

I have AEM instance setup on a AWS Ubuntu machine. Not sure why stop command not working for publish instance. It is working fine for author instance. We have configured it on changed port(5054). Can anyone suggest if I am missing anything? Here is the screen shot showing the error message while running the stop command:

[image]

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2326343

Comment: you can stop the AEM instance that way only if you started it with the start script. did you start it with crx-quickstart/start ? or how did you start it ?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam, I think that may be a catch although I have found that my publish instance was already stopped after 1 hours of executing stop command. But I am not sure if this is because of any other network intervention. I have started my publish instance with command "java -jar AEM-publish-5054.jar -r publish". I am wondering what's the command to stop instance in this case.

Comment: If you look at the start and stop scripts, they create a pid file on start and delete it on stop. So if you did not start AEM with start script, you cannot stop it with stop script. I believe there is an option in osgi console, to stop the java process, if that does not work, find the java process PID and kill it, then start with the start script.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam, can you put your comment as an answer, as I think this is the suitable answer for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You cannot stop an AEM instance with the `stop` script if you did not start it with the `start` script.

If you look at the scripts you'll see that:

`start` script creates a file `conf/cq.pid` that has the java PID

`stop` script looks for that file and tries to stop the instance then deletes the file.

Thus, if you did not start with `start` script, you cannot stop with `stop` script.